# Click on a button in a table when button name changes periodically

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm using Python and Selenium to click through a site to select and reserve a room.  The site presents a table of rooms available.  I want to find a specific room and click on the button in the table that is associated with that room....but the button name changes depending on where the room is located in the table.  Where it is located depends, in part, on what other rooms are available at the time I run through the website.

In this example, I want to reserve 'Room 34".

The table appears to be identified by:

```
<table id="MainContent_tblPage"....>
```

The row or section of the table that includes "Room 34" is identified by the following (which changes depending on where Room 34 appears in the table...which depends on how many other rooms are available):

```
<tr id=MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_1" >
```

The button I want to click in this example is:

```
name="_ctl0:MainContent:rptrPropertyList:_ctl2:rptPropertyRooms:
_ctl0:btnSelect"
```

(...but the button name changes depending on which other rooms appear in the table...)

My question:  How do I find and click the correct button in a table if the button name changes dynamically depending on table content/rows...but the button is always in a row with the text I want to find?

HTML of the section I'm looking at (...sorry, I'm not sure how to make it more readable without the possibility of changes things that might be important for answering my question):

```
<table id="tblPropertyList" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">                                 
                                        <tbody><tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_0">
                                        ##...snip...similar code as shown under  <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_1"> below...
                                        ##...I cut it out to save space but I can add it back if it helps  --JRrcgp                                 

                                        <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_1">
        <td class="room_grid_row">
                                                <table cellpading="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" class="room_grid_heading_2">
                                                               Hornswoggle Tower
                                                                              <br><span class="text2">CityPlace</span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="right" valign="top">
                                                          <div class="room_grid_image">
                                                              <a onclick="javascript:ShowGallery('lightSlider_1');" title="Room 34">
                                                              <img src="imgHandler.ashx?image=\\fileserver.inncenter.pms.inrd.live\\Share1\\Assets/pics/roomClass_pic_8455.jpg" id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_Image1_1" onerror="showNoImage(this);" style="visibility:true;">
                                                                  </a>
                                                          </div>
                                                          <div class="demo">
                                                            <ul id="lightSlider_1" style="display:none">

                                                                        <li data-thumb="imgHandler.ashx?image=\\fileserver.inncenter.pms.inrd.live\\Share1\\Assets/pics/roomClass_pic_8455.jpg">
                                                                            <img src="imgHandler.ashx?image=\\fileserver.inncenter.pms.inrd.live\\Share1\\Assets/pics/roomClass_pic_8455.jpg">
                                                                        </li>

                                                            </ul>
                                                          </div>
                                                      </td>
                                                        <td valign="top" width="100%" class="padding_left_1">
                                                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <td class="room_grid_heading" colspan="3">
                                                                              <div class="floatleft">                                                                       
                                                                            Room 34
                                                                                  </div>
                                                                              <div class="floatright">
                                                                                     <span class="room_grid_from_rate_text1">From </span>
                                                                                    <span id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_lblMinRate_1" class="room_grid_from_rate_text2">$88</span>
                                                                                    <!--<span class="room_grid_from_rate_text1">/Night</span>-->
                                                                                  </div>

                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="3">
                                                                            <table width="100%" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                                    <td valign="top" class="room_grid_discription_2">

                                                                                                <span id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_reptSectionInline_1_lblSectionInline_0" class="more"><font face="Verdana">Text description of room.</font></span>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                                        <tbody><tr>

                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                </tr>                                                                                
                                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_tdSingleRate_1" style="display: none;">
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                            <font class="Bold"> $<span id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_lblratePrice_1">88</span><br></font> per night
                                                                        </td>

                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                       <td valign="bottom" align="left">
                                                                                                    <table align="left" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                                        <td align="left" nowrap="" width="80%" class="displayRatePlan"><span class="room_grid_rateplanname">
                                                                                                Best Available Rate
                                                                                            </span><span class="room_grid_rateplan_moreinfo">(<a class="thickbox" id="lnkMoreInfo" title="Best Available Rate" href="#TB_inline?height=Div8&amp;width=Div7&amp;inlineId=MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_Div9_0">More Info</a>)</span>

                                                                                            <div id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_Div9_0" class="roomClassSection" style="display: none;">
                                                                                                                    <div class="popupWidth" id="Div7">
                                                                                                                        <div class="popupHeight" id="Div8">                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                            <table class="more_info_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" border="0">
                                                                                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                                                                        <div id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_excludeRoom_DIV_0">

                                                                                                                                                    </div></td></tr><tr>
                                                                                                                                                        <td class="alt1">
                                                                                                                                                         Name:
                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                        <td style="width: 90%">
                                                                                                                                                            Room Rate
                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                                                                        <td class="alt1">
                                                                                                                                                           Date:
                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                                                                                            Fri, Apr 27, 2018 - Sun, Apr 29, 2018
                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                                                                                        <td class="alt1">
                                                                                                                                                            Policy:
                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                        <td>

                                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                                    </tr>



                                                                                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                        </td> 
                                                                                        <td id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_tdRateDescription_0" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" width="12%">
                                                                                            <span class="room_grid_fullrate">

                                                                                               $188


                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                            <span class="room_grid_fullrate_avgnightly">
                                                                                            &nbsp;<span id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_lblRateMsg_0">(Avg nightly rate)</span></span>
                                                                                        </td>

                                                                                        <td width="8%" align="left">
                                                                            <input type="submit" name="_ctl0:MainContent:rptrPropertyList:_ctl2:rptPropertyRooms:_ctl0:btnSelect" value="Select" onclick="ShowProgress();" language="javascript" id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_rptPropertyRooms_1_btnSelect_0" class="button green">
                                                                        </td>


                                                                                    </tr>


                                                                            </tbody></table>                                                      
                                                                        </td>                                                                            
                                                                    </tr>                                                                        
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                            </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </td>
    </tr>


                                        <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_2">
                                        ##...snip...similar code as shown under  <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_1"> above...
                                        <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_3">
                                        ##...snip...similar code as shown under  <tr id="MainContent_rptrPropertyList_trContent_1"> above...
                                        ##...this continues to repeat once for each room available
```

EDIT: I'm currently working past this issue by hard-coding the button I'm clicking.  I use Selenium to navigate to the webpage that creates a table of the rooms available and then I click on the appropriate button as it stands today.  But the name of the button will change in the future:

```
room34 = browser.find_element_by_name('_ctl0:MainContent:rptrPropertyList:_ctl31:rptPropertyRooms:_ctl0:btnSelect')
room34.click()
```

EDIT 2:  I've played the suggestion from @Grasshopper.  His code didn't work for me, but I made some changes that I thought made progress....I was mistaken.  I'm removing the rest of Edit 2 so as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: If it is the only HTML elemet in the table just search for the element by HTML tag name that is inside the table. This way you are for sure find it no matter what name it has.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post all your code so we can see it.

Comment: @Alex...I didn't post my code because all I've done so far is to hardwire the name of the button I want to click.  So I use Selenium to successfully navigate to the page listing the rooms and then my code is hardwired to the Room 34 button as it stands today (but it will change in the future based on which other rooms are available and used to build the table on the page).  I'll add that code above to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the button with `name` as **_ctl0:MainContent:rptrPropertyList:_ctl2:rptPropertyRooms:_ctl0:btnSelect** with respect to the element with text as **Room 34** you can use either of the following line of code :

- Using `following` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='room_grid_image']/a[contains(@title,'Room 34')]//following::input[1]").click()
  ```
- Using `following-sibling` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='room_grid_image']/a[contains(@title,'Room 34')]//following-sibling::input[1]").click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you!  Both of these worked perfectly.  I tried them with multiple search criteria in the pages leading up to the page with the table in order to make sure the room was displayed in different rows and, each time, it found the room and clicked on the correct button.

Comment: Thanks again...I've spent hours on this.  Well, I spend hours on everything as I'm a rank beginner, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath - `"//div[normalize-space(.)='Room 34']/ancestor::tbody/tr/td//input[@type='submit']"`

The 'Room 34' can be substituted by a python variable. `normalize-space` is required as the text has a lot of white space.

Comment: @Grasshopper...thank you for the suggestion.  I couldn't get it to work.  The final line of the error I'm receiving is:  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[normalize-space(.)='Room 34']/ancestor::tbody/tr/td//input[@type='submit']

Comment: I've been playing with your suggestion.  Please see Edit 2 to my original question.

Comment: Use ActionChains to move to the element using move_to_element.  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html